# Why does my program screen dims down?

Tags: linux, display, window, display-settings

I wrote a program to run on Linux OS. I noticed whenever I ran the program and clicked on a button to open a window, sometimes the main application screen dims down. This doesn't happen on all the Linux Distribution. And I can't seem to figure out why or how to stop it. I am using Mangiea distribution and used Lazarus 1.0.12 to code my program. If someone could give me a hint or clue, I would appreciated.

Comment: Some window managers do this for unresponsive programs.

Comment: @frostschutz Can this also happen when you open a dialog window?

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question was asked last year by me, I want to throw in my 2 cents. Just recently I had a chance to run my program on two different Linux distributions and noticed that my program acted the same way - opening other windows by clicking on a button dimmed down the main screen. And if you again opened another window from this window its parent window dimmed down as well. However, when you close these windows, dimmed down windows don't become normal rather it was random or hit and miss. This bugged me a lot. So, I figured out why. This is because of WINDOWS EFFECTS (System Settings -> Windows Appearance). I disabled all the WINDOWS EFFECT OPTIONS and now it does not dim any windows. Plus, it looks more clean. I answered my own question to help anyone who might run into this issue.